# Why is the object property not updated in the updateObject() method in Java?

Tags: java, oop, object, methods, arguments

```
public class Employee {

    int age = 32;
    String name = "Kevin";

    public Employee updateEmployee(Employee e) {
        e = new Employee();
        e.age = 56;
        e.name = "Jeff";
        return e;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Employee t = new Employee();
        t.updateEmployee(t);
        System.out.println("age= " + t.age + " " + "name= " + " " + t.name);

    }

}
```

===================

```
OUTPUT:-
age= 32 name=  Kevin
```

Why is the output not 56 and Jeff. I updated the object reference "t" in the method? Please help.

Comment: You created a new Employee, that no longer has anything to do with the passed in `t`.

Comment: why are you doing `e = new Employee();` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see that in an IDE may be you will get a warning from the,

```
updateEmployee() method
```

stating,

```
The return value is not used anywhere, you can make the return type as void
```

As **Java is always pass-by-value,** if you need to update an object's state, then assign the return (updated) value back to it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Employee t = new Employee();
    t = t.updateEmployee(t);
    System.out.println("age= " + t.age + " " + "name= " + " " + t.name);
}
```

Output:

```
age= 56 name=  Jeff
```

`Edit:` It would be better if your update method just work on that `this` ref.

```
public void updateEmployee() {
    this.age = 56;
    this.name = "Jeff";
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Employee t = new Employee();
    t.updateEmployee();
    System.out.println("age= " + t.age + " " + "name= " + " " + t.name);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I agree to that.. I jus tried to point out what was missing @Ivar

Comment: My bad.. yeah..